# Swift String interpolation not working when it's parsed from a file

Tags: swift, string-interpolation

I am encoding a string with interpolation:

> `let name = "John"
>   "My name is \(name)"`
>
> to a file

And i need to decode that string from file when running my code, i am expecting the string to print `My name is John`, but all i get is `My name is \(name)`

Is there a way to let Swift understand string interpolation in this case?

Comment: it's a bad idea and is not possible, since the app would crash in case the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: my file is guaranteed to have the variable in it... So i guess it is not possible.

Comment: a variable can not exist in a text file

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The proposed solution ignores the fact that your example should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution could be to use `String(format:)` and use any variable you want when parsing

Write "My name is %s" to file and then when reading it

```
let inString = "My name is %s"  //from file really
let str = String(format: inString, "John")
```